# Updating new fields in my model

Tags: python, django, field, django-models

I'm trying to update new fields in my db about my "card" model that already had fields above, but I have a problem that impede me do this process:

When I ran ./manage.py syncdb I got this message:

```
Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

So I ran makemigrations command but...

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'imagen' to card without a default;
we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

I chose press the second option and add the requirement myself, actually I have this:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class subscriber(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        nombreCompleto = "%s %s"%(self.nombre,self.apellidos)
        return nombreCompleto

def url(self,filename):
    ruta = "MultimediaData/Card/%s/%s"%(self.nombre,str(filename))
    return ruta

class card(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=url)
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

If I modify "Imagen" Field like said the message I would do as follows:

imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=url, default='')

But then the same message appear after having made ​​the same modification to "imagen" field:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'precio' to card without a default;
we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
```

And finally this last:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'stock' to card without a default;
we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
```

If I modify all these fields, I finally can run ./manage.py makemigrations:

```
Migrations for 'synopticup':
  0002_auto_20141016_2004.py:
    - Add field imagen to card
    - Add field precio to card
    - Add field stock to card
```

But when I run ./manage.py syncdb I obtain this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: [u"'' value must be a decimal number."]
```

What's wrong with my process? I prefered leave all as they were before:

```
class card(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=url)
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
```

apologizeme in advance my extensive question and if I overlook something.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default for a `DecimalField` should be a `Decimal` object.

```
from decimal import Decimal

class card(models.Model):
    # ...
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=url, default='')
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0))
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```